# Beautiful rain drop lights using multiple NE 555

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

This 74HC595 is used to create rain drop lights as shown in this Youtube video at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpSw8oS_80s&t=387s&ab_channel=Kiyani%27sLab). Is there a way to replicate this using multiple NE 555 timers?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if you can replace the shift register with additional timers?

Comment: If not replacing the shift register as @JYelton asks, what would the function of the additional timers be?

Comment: Is it *possible* ... ? Probably ... but it would be a monumental PitA and would need a bunch of additional add-on discrete parts too.

Comment: As shown, most of the control pins of the 74HC595 are not connected and will make the circuit behave unpredictably (i.e. purely dependent on noise picked up at the inputs). This would not be easy to replicate with 555s. The question is: why would you want to?

Comment: are you asking if the 595 can be replaced with 555 timers, then probably yes, if you can get the 555s for free. as it would probably take about 10

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is not guaranteed to work even as shown, so you'd want to fix it before replicating it. For example, if there's any moisture condensation on it, it'll likely not work.

There are lots of videos and tutorials out there that show circuits that "work" only in right circumstances, and the people who post these things have not enough integrity to admit how finicky a design might be. Good designs, especially those destined for experimenter/non-specialist market, should work in a variety of conditions and should not depend on very tight component specifications, or they should specify an adjustment procedure that will work without special skills and with rudimentary tools only.

A PC board or a breadboard are most definitely a component even if many people don't think of it that way: it has parasitic impedances that greatly affect the performance of such a circuit.

Most people who'd try to replicate this circuit would probably be disappointed.

You can't leave the CMOS logic inputs floating. There are at least two approaches that would work for this circuit:

1. Make it properly sensitive to random noise, and for that you'd probably want two diode or mosfet (2N7000 is great!) noise sources, a single or maybe two-stage transistor amplifier for each, and a Schmitt trigger buffer to generate valid logic signals for the input and output clocks.
2. Make the register longer - the outputs don't need to be connected to LEDs if you don't want them to - and add a couple external gates to build a LFSR (linear feedback shift register). The LFSR feedback must be set up to guarantee operation from any initial state, since the initial state is generally unknown. Then the circuit will be deterministic but behave chaotically. Then add a constant clock source using e.g. a 555, or a random clock source using low-pass filtered noise source as in idea #1 above.

As for re-implementing it with 555 timers: sure, these chips are flexible enough that you could "coax" them into replicating any two-input logic function, and flip-flops as well, and certainly you could turn them into some sort of a shift register with chaotic behavior.

I might revisit this answer later to show how it could be done. But both this HC595-based circuit, when properly done, as well as one using 555 timers as the only active devices, would be more complex than just one chip, and a circuit using 555s would have a dozen or two chips in it.

Comment: Hi sir, I am eager to wait for your answer !! Please show a schematic :)